# Is this a correct translation of "I don't want them to die"?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, traduction

Is "Je ne veux pas qu'ils à mourir" a good translation or should you use "Je ne veux pas qu'ils meurent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Je ne veux pas qu'ils à mourir* is incorrect / ungrammatical.

*Je ne veux pas qu'ils meurent* is fine and likely the best translation you can use.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is correct.

In French, you don't use `à` before infinitives to indicate the "to", it's implied.

Comment: "Je ne veux pas le décès d'eux" is not correct French. You might say "Je ne veux pas de leur décès" but that doesn't translate well "I don't want them to die".

Comment: ah, you're right, thanks! I'm currently learning French, there are spots like that that I still have to iron out ^^"

Answer (score 1):

An alternative word for meurent is périssent

"Je ne veux pas qu'ils périssent"

Comment: You should note that "périr" is a bit old-fashionned

Comment: You could present a balance of your older alternative with a newer one: "[Je {ne} peux pas les pifer mais] je {ne} veux/voudrais pas qu'ils [claquent](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/claquer) quand même!"